# Tweet Video with Tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I saw that you figured out how to tweet videos with Tweepy. I was wondering if you could point me in the right direction to also figure out how to do it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tweet a video with Tweepy is still unsupported, see https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/640

It is currently possible to tweet multiple images